# Javascript export destructuring default keyword

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

I have the following code: `export { default } from 'app';` and I can't work out whether the default keyword means that the export is defining a default export, or that `app` has an export called default that is being destructured and then the export is exporting an object called default? Basically I'm very confused by this line and would appreciate some explanation.

Comment: you can't use default cause default is spec in js. please look at examples here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export

Comment: "*the export is defining a default export, or that app has an export called default*" - that's the same thing. No, it's not an object, and there's no destructuring here. It's short for `export { default as default } from 'app';`.

Comment: @HalilÇakar You can use `default` just fine in that place.

Comment: As far as i know you can't really use default as name

Comment: @HalilÇakar You can name your exports whatever you like. Exporting with the name `default` even has extra syntactic sugar.

Comment: Aight I'm not talking about `export default {}` I was talking about `export default default` but my explanation was not good enough i'm guessing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the export is defining a default export, or `app` has an export called default

That's the same thing. No, it's not an object, and there's no destructuring here. It's short for

```
export { default as default } from 'app';
```

and does re-export the default export of `app` as the default export of the current module. In two lines, spelled out explicitly and introducing a local `app` binding, it would be

```
import { default as app } from 'app';
export { app as default }
```

where the second line is similar (but not identical!) to the more prevalent `export default app`.

Comment: Would you mind elaborating? Because I think if you `export default default` in the `app`, that will throw an error

Comment: @ABGR After `export default …` some value expression must follow, like `export default 42;`. The reserved name `default` in that position would be a variable identifier and is indeed an error.

Comment: All I have seen is `import ... from 'app';` `export ...from 'app'` is new to me.

Comment: Yes please elaborate, I still don't understand what that line is doing. Maybe also include an some equivalent code that is broken into two lines will help clarify what it is doing.

Comment: @Max888 It's not really possible to break this apart into multiple lines without introducing extra identifiers. It would be something like `import { default as app } from 'app'; export { app as default }` however. Or, breaking the alias (live reference), `import app from 'app'; export default app;`

Comment: Thank you, that makes more sense. Is the second line equivalent to `export default app`?

Comment: @Bergi but the OP is specifically asking if `export { default } from 'app';` is valid. I don't think it is.

Comment: @ABGR It is. Did you try it?

Comment: I did try `import  { default } from 'app';` though. That didn't work.

Comment: @Max888 `export default app` is more like `const _default = app; export { _default as default }`.

Comment: @ABGR Yes, `import { default } from …` doesn't work, as the local binding (module-scope variable) must have a valid identifier. `import { default as app } from …` would work.

Comment: @Bergi, ah I see you added further explanation on the second line. I am going to add it to your answer if you don't mind as I think it helps explain what is happening in a rough but easy to understand sense

Comment: Also please considering upvoting my question, I think it is a good valid question that has not been answered before on SO so doesn't deserve to be downvoted

Comment: I'm still having hard time wapping my head around probably because of `export { default } from 'app';` @Max888 did you mean `import` here? As you can't have both `export` and `from` in the same same sentence

Comment: @ABGR [Yes you can](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export#Syntax)

Answer (score -1):

`default` is a part of the language, when you export something and want to export it without restructuring you use `export default`, there's no way around not having it unless you don't use es6 modules.

Comment: if you have doubts, provide a link to where someone tells you to use this import

Answer (score -1):

Keywords cannot be used as identifier of variable/functions, because they have special meaning to the language. You need to rename it.

However, to rename a property when destructuring, here it is :

`export { defaultName as newName} from 'app';`

Comment: Exports do not need to be identifiers.

Comment: Oooh, sorry my bad. I thought it was an import ... 

to export : 

`export defaultName;`
`export default defaultName;` .

Comment: you can still use destructuring if needed for an export

Comment: `as` is not destructuring.

Comment: as is not destructuring, but `{ property1 }  = object1` is.
But I got your point... Thank you for the clarifications ;) I am mixing things...